# How to nderstand OwinHttpListener.SetRequestProcessingLimits

Tags: owin, katana, owin-middleware

```
var owinHttpListener = (OwinHttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener"];

int maxAccepts, maxRequests;
maxAccepts = Int32.MaxValue; //Default = 5 * ProcCount
maxRequests = Int32.MaxValue; //Default = Int32.MaxValue;
owinHttpListener.SetRequestProcessingLimits(maxAccepts, maxRequests);
```

The `OwinHttpListener.SetRequestProcessingLimits` from above example code accepts two parameters according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.host.httplistener.owinhttplistener.setrequestprocessinglimits(v=vs.113).aspx).

- `maxAccepts` The maximum number of pending request receives.
- `maxRequests` The maximum number of active requests being processed.

What I don't understand is the `maxAccepts` parameter. Accept here means TCP accept?  HTTP head received?

Can someone help to clarify what does the `maxAccepts` parameter mean?

Comment: This controls how many requests the server attempts to process concurrently I guess.

Comment: I assume there is some counter wihtin OWIN implementation, and if the counter exceeds the limitation,  no more request is accepted.  What I want to understand is:  when this counter is increased / decreased

Answer (score 0):

You can see for yourself in the [Katana source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener/OwinHttpListener.cs), namely method `ProcessRequestsAsync()`.

The `outstandingAccepts` counter is incremented between the time the TCP connection is accepted (by the underlying `HttpListener`), and until a 'request context' is generated from it, I assume by parsing the HTTP header (method [`HttpListener.GetContextAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.getcontextasync?view=netframework-4.6.2&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.HttpListener.GetContextAsync)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.6.2)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) ).
At that point, the `outstandingAccepts` counter is decremented.

Then `outstandingRequests++`, and the actual "semantic" processing of the request starts in the OWIN service.
Finally, `outstandingRequests--` when the request processing completes (one way or another).

TL;DR:

- Accepts: wait for connection + get request context (probably) by parsing headers
- Requests: execute the request context in OWIN.